# MKCoordinateRegionForMapRect returns invalid region in iPhone 4s and iPhone 5 simulators ONLY

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview, mapkit, xcode6

This is somewhat bemusing. The below code is an example - I am creating a region based off an MKMapRect. The below is an approximate bounding box for the UK.

When I use this code in the iPhone 4s and iPhone 5 simulators, an invalid region is returned. As such, when I set the maps region to this value the app crashes.

```
let boundOrigin = MKMapPoint(x: 126073944, y: 78054668)
let boundSize = MKMapSize(width: 9759383, height: 13846126)
let boundedRect = MKMapRect(origin: boundOrigin, size: boundSize)
let boundedRegion = MKCoordinateRegionForMapRect(boundedRect)
```

In the iPhone 5s (and above) simulators the correct region is returned and there is no crash.

I have an actual iPhone 4s so I tested this on the device and it works fine.

Is this a bug with the simulator?

I am using Version 8.0 (550.1) of the simulator from within XCode 6 Version 6.0.1 (6A317) and I am targeting iOS 8 using Swift yadda yadda :)

If anyone could clear this up for me that would be great. I'm not sure if I should be concerned given that it works on the actual device..

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you create a coordinate region directly using latitude and longitude? Using an MkMapRect is going to depend in the device display, map zoom and so on.

Comment: This is a small piece of a larger puzzle - I'm trying to do some pretty complex things with maps. I appreciate your point though. Plus at this point I'm intrigued as to if this is actually a bug..

Comment: It just seems that working in an arbitrary coordinate space that could change over time is risky compared to a fixed coordinate system (continental drift excepted)

Comment: Could you clarify? Has Apple said anything to this effect?

Comment: [See the discussion regarding the MKMapPoint struct in the docs.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/mapkit/reference/MapKitDataTypesReference/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/MKMapPoint).  I believe the docs are saying that the conversion of latitude/longitude to MKMapPoint and back is not guaranteed to be the same across iOS versions and that MKMapPoint values should be calculated and used during run-time only.